# Count people standing in front of our Kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect

We are making an interactive installation with a Kinect, and we need to know how many people are standing / walking slowly in front of our installation.

We will count up to 5 people, if there is more we don't care.

To do that we take the total volume of blobs detected by the Kinect, divide it by the approximative volume of 1 person.

```
count = Vtotal / Vperson;
```

Finally, to smoothen the count, we calculate the average count on 2 seconds.

```
countAvg = Vtotalavg / Vperson;
```

This works OK-ish for 2-3 people, but when there is more, the blobs overlap, and the total volume doesn't seem to be relevant anymore.

Does somebody have an idea how we could solve this and have a reliable count ... either by using the same blob volume method, or something smarter !?

Comment: If you are not dead set on openCV, openFrameworks has a simple to implement solution for doing skeleton tracking.

Comment: what is that solution ? Any pointer to API docs ?

Comment: There are two - ofxKinect and ofxOpenNI (https://github.com/gameoverhack/ofxOpenNI) - ofxOpenNI seems the more developed, last time I checked. Worth the hour it would take to test it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ceiling-mount the kinect. Point it straight down at the floor. Take raw depth data and filter any pixels further away than a certain threshold that tends to capture heads and shoulders only. (Try everything higher than 4 feet.) Of those pixels, examine each group of contiguous pixels and get a total pixel count for that group. If the group pixel count is less than a minimum threshold, ignore it. You could now just count each group as one person, but a further refinement helps catch people standing very close: divide the group pixel count by an average-pixels-per-person constant and round to nearest value.

It works.

Comment: Yes, this is really good. And actually we don't even have to modify anything in the code (except capture depth and `average-pixels-per-person` aka our `Vperson`) to implement this solution. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

but why you do that ? Kinect gives a Skeleton id for each skeleton in front of him that is tracked. Simple make an array (size 5) and put the tracked skeletons there. To count them you just get number of elements in array

Comment: Yes ... it would probably be easier :) however we are just using tools that we know how to use, and in such a short time frame we cannot dive into this ! So unfortunately we will have to get the thing working without that ... just by finding a smart way of using the data we have.

Comment: i'm not too familiar with opencv but standard in standard kinect sdk i can get tracked skeleton in 1 code line. So IMO you should look into opencv. Cause as you can see your method is problematic

Comment: With kinect sdk, does it get messed up if people pass in front of each other ?

Comment: yes it can but imo if you use open source sdk you`ll also have this problem. If you`re interested read about new SDK. Last app i wrote in before 1.5 and in early 1.5 so I may be a bit out of date :) I just think that if the solution is simpler than it is better

Comment: Of course ! But then in the short run it won't solve our problem. Maybe we'll save a few lines of code, but we'll find the same problem eventually. I'll try to come up with a smart algorithm using what we already have :)

Comment: I'm agree with Fixus. Kinect Sdk can detect up to 6 persons, if you open the sample of skeleton tracking, and add just one line int persons = skeletons.Lenght; get that you want.